# Retrieve data from controls loaded into a flowlayoutpanel

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, flowlayoutpanel

First a picture of how the app is set up:

[image: App]

Each time the user hits the "Add Character" another Character box will show up, they are custom controls.

What I am lost on how to do is gather all the inputs from all the Character boxes when I hit the save button.

Comment: Use a `List<Character>` variable, call its Add() method whenever you add another one.  Now it is simple.  Do keep in mind that UI like this scales very poorly, it is only suitable for, at best, a few dozen "characters".  Both to the OS and your user.  Alternative is a listview that lets the user select a character to edit.

Comment: Thank you for your input Hans, however, implementing your solution would not actually retrieve the data that would be added when the user fills in the textboxes and numericupdowns. Scaling does not matter as the use case for this application should not have the user needing more than a dozen or two characters.

I do use a list in my final solution, but i use it in conjunction with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Controls` Property of the `FlowLayoutPanel` will help you to do the trick.

Edit: since your structure is `CharacterControl` inside the `FlowLayoutPanel` and everything else inside the `CharacterControl`, you can do it like this

```
foreach (CharacterControl charControl in flow1.Controls) {
        //do something with control
        //cast Control to the correct control type by using its Name property whenever necessary
        //collect all the Text/value in the control here!, save it afterwards!
}
```

Comment: so I will need to access `CharacterControl.charName.Text` in each of the charactercontrol controls. How would I do this?

Comment: This is WinForms, right? is your CharacterControl is of type `FlowLayoutPanel`?

Comment: Yes it is winforms, and no CharacterControl is each box of controls you see in the image, they are each an instance of CharacterControl. (For the purpose of the image I clicked "Add Character" 6 times)

Comment: I see, and do you happen to have a class describing each of the `FlowLayoutPanel` completely? Because if you do have, things will get easier. But if you don't you should do iteration loop like I showed. Then for each control (you know the name you give for each of them I suppose), based on the name, you can categorize them into different (more specific) control types such as `TextBox`, `Button`, `Label`, `DateTimePicker`, or `NumericUpDown`, then you only take those which you want to store (for instance, you do not want to store `Button.Text` or `Label.Text`, I suppose)

Comment: Then, in case you only need the `Text` of the `Control` that you already filter, you can simply grab it by (using my code example above) control.Text, then you will get what is texted. Save it as you wish.

Comment: I have ONLY 1 flowlayoutpanel! The CharacterControl is its own control, just like a TextBox would be. Because of this and your edit, your last comment doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I think it is better to continue in the chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98665/discussion-between-user1720845-and-ian).